# jQuery Tokeninput prePopulate not working with nested_form

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, jquery-tokeninput

I've implemented [jQuery Tokeninput](https://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/) as a tagging mechanism on my `Chain` model and everything works nicely. Now I'm attempting to abstract the tagging field so that it can work with multiple models and I can't get the data to prePopulate correctly. I'm also using the [nested_form](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form) plugin.

The premise is that my `Chain` has_many `Events` so when I edit a `Chain`, I'd also like to edit the associated `Events`. Both the `Chain` and associated `Events` can be tagged independently.

Here's the related view structure:
github.com/chrbradley/EVEnT/blob/master/app/views/chains/edit.html.erb)

```
<%= render partial: 'form', locals: { chain: @chain } %>
```

github.com/chrbradley/EVEnT/blob/master/app/views/chains/_form.html.erb

```
<%= nested_form_for @chain do |f| %>
  <div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :title %>
  <%= f.text_field :title, class: "form-control" %>
  <%= f.label :description %>
  <%= f.text_area :description, class: "form-control" %>
<%= render 'tag_fields', f: f, tags: @chain.tags %><br />
...
<%= f.fields_for :events do |builder| %>
  <%= render 'event_fields', f: builder %>
<% end %>
...
```

github.com/chrbradley/EVEnT/blob/master/app/views/chains/_event_fields.html.erb)

```
<%= render 'tag_fields', tags: f.object.tags, f: f %>
```

github.com/chrbradley/EVEnT/blob/master/app/views/chains/_tag_fields.html.erb)

```
<%= f.text_field :tag_tokens, data: {load: tags}, class: 'js-tokenizer' %>
```

github.com/chrbradley/EVEnT/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/chains.js.coffee)

```
$('.js-tokenizer').tokenInput('/tags.json', {
  theme: 'mac',
  prePopulate: $('.js-tokenizer').data('load'),
  preventDuplicates: true})
```

So as it stands now, this results in the `Chain` tags getting prePopulated into all of the `<%= f.text_field :tag_tokens, data:...` fields on the `_tags_fields` partial for each event. If I save from here, all of the `Event` tags get saved with the `Chain` tags.

When I inspect the tag field element on any of the events, the html shows that the tag list is comprised of the tags from the `Chain` but immediately after the `</ul>` for a given `Event` is `<input class="js-tokenizer" data-load="[{...` where the `...` is a hash with all of the correct tags.

This indicates to me, a Rails and JS noob, that the problem is with the `prePopulate` function in `chains.js.coffee`. Also, if I remove the call to the `_tag_fields` partial from `_form`, so I'm just attempting to edit the tags on the `Events`, all of the tag fields get populated with the tags from the first event. I'm not sure what's happening here so any help will be greatly appreciated.

Also sine my reputation is lacking, I can't include more than 2 links, so if somebody can be so kind as to reformat this post.